# Mac OS X Time Machine recovery lost Data

Tags: macos, time-machine

I did a backup with Time Machine on a Netgear ReadyNAS to save complete System(OS X Mavericks). Because I have installed OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Now I recovered this backup. But I lost about 200 GB of 360GB.

Has anybody an idea to recover this lost data from SSD?

Comment: What do you mean by lost? Did you exclude some folder in the time machine preferences? How did you restore?

Comment: I didn't modify the time machine preferences in detail - no excluded folders. I restored the System with the system-restore during boot.

Comment: Which folders have not been restored? Are they still on the Time Machine disk (just browse it in Finder)? What exactly do you mean by "system-restore" (did you just reinstall 10.9 or did you pick the option to restore from a TM backup)?

Comment: Music, Pictures and Movie of my user account haven't restored. No, I didn't find those folders on the time machine disk. I restored the system from a TM backup.

Comment: Do you have any indication that these folders got backed up to the TM disk in the first place then? Otherwise they are most probably lost :-(

Comment: Yes I have already restored the system but I don't think that still exists this backup. :(

Answer (score 3):

This answer you provided in the chat above is important:

> Music, Pictures and Movie of my user account haven't restored. No, I didn't find those folders on the time machine disk.

If those folders are not present on the Time Machine disk as you indicate above, then they weren't being backed up by Time Machine. You have lost this data and there is no way to get it back.